# Unknown column in field list vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Connected to `mysql` database with vb.net

When i want to add number through application to `Mysql` database no problems.

When i type word/letter in field it always popups `Unknown column 'text' in 'field list'`

I checked the type in `mysql` database of the field users it is set to `'Varchar' max 50`

To add record i use query

```
 query = "insert into table tableName (users,website,amount) values (" + txtname.Text + ",'" + txtsite.Text + "','" + txtamount.Text + "')"
```

Comment: no table name?? and what about amount column? convention says it could be numeric type. so convert txtamount.Text to numeric type.

Comment: do let me know if the updated solution worked and if not which else solution worked

Comment: Was missing single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and you are missing single quotes after

```
values(
```

corrected query with quotes (and assumption that amount column could be of numeric type. If it is non-numeric you can keep the query as it is):

```
query = "insert into table tableName(users,website,amount) values ('" + txtname.Text + "','" + txtsite.Text + "','" + Convert.ToDecimal(txtamount.Text) + "')" // or Convert.ToInt64 whichever it could be
```

Comment: It is Varchar type i don't need to convert it ?

Comment: check update. I've added a pair of quote marks for txtname.Text. may that is the problem

Comment: Works great now. Thanks a lot just one more thing how would Update data query go ? 

     `query = "update tableName (Users,Website,Amount) values ("' + txtname.Text + ",'" + txtsite.Text + "','" + txtamount.Text + "')"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer i'm really trying to update entire table like this  `query = "Update * from bazatestna.logiranje where Users='" & txtname.Text & "'"`  also tried  `query = "update bazatestna.logiranje set Users='" & txtname.Text & "' Website ='" & txtsite.Text & " 'Amount ='" & txtamount.Text & "'"`

Comment: It's wrong. Try posting this as new question in SO. you will get prompt replies. We can't discuss these in comments :P

Comment: i need to wait 1:30 -.-