# SQL QUERY Unknown column <unknown column name> in <unknown field list>

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I have the following code which is used to save to a MySQL database. As I execute my code I get the following error:

> ERROR: Unknown column 'User' in 'NEW'

This is my code:

```
Dim DBconnSTRs As String = conn.connects
Dim DBconns As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection = New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(DBconnSTRs)
DBconns.Open()
Dim sqlcmd As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
Dim sqls As String
sqls = "INSERT INTO tblwalkin(CatalogID,Picture,DateIn,TimeIn,Quarter,Semester,SchoolYear,CompName) VALUES (@catalogid,@pics,@dtein,@tmein,@quart,@sem,@sy,@pc)"
'Try
With sqlcmd
    .CommandText = sqls
    .Connection = DBconns
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@catalogid", catid)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@pics", db.ConvertToBytes(PictureBox2))
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtein", String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day))
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@tmein", TimeOfDay)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@quart", cbQuarter.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sem", lblsem.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@sy", lblSY.Text)
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("@pc", "")
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

As you can see in my query, the column `USER` is not included anywhere and I don't know where the `NEW` comes from.

I have tried to CLEAN, REBUILD then SAVE all. I have also tried to change the variable names in my program and the column names in my database.

Can anyone see why this error is occurring?

Comment: it highlights the .EXECUTION NON QUERY() where will the error show

Comment: Break the query and see if the error message changes.  E.g. remove `@pc` from the `VALUES` clause, leaving only 7 values.

Comment: catid there is just a Primary key from the other table

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok wait.. let me try

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it says "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" when pc is removed from VALUES

Comment: OK...then maybe your code is really generating this error.

Comment: Are any of the data being inserted varchar?  You might have to put single quotes around the values.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201561/unknown-column-in-field-list-vb-net

Comment: Use `.Parameters.Add` rather than `.AddWithValue` and explicitly set each data type.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes.. the Quarter, Semester, SchoolYear is a varchar type

Comment: @Jinx88909 I tried to change it to Parameters.Add.. still the same error also it produces a warning.. saying that the ADD is "deprecated"

Comment: Try setting the parameters `?` rather than the `@name`. I think MySQL only cares about the order in which they are declared. It's worth a go. Very strange error to be getting. Not sure what the value of `db.ConvertToBytes(PictureBox2))` is, maybe that is causing an issue?

Comment: @Jinx88909 it's a picturebox, calling the function ConvertToByte converting it to bytes for the BLOB datatype to MySql..I tried to remove that for a while then execute the code again.. still the error is Unknown column 'User' in 'NEW'... highlighting the .ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Ok well then let's try and think a little more outside of your code as your code does look fine. Are there any triggers on the table `tblwalkin`?

Comment: Do you have any triggers in your database? Everything I see on this error using 'New' points to a trigger issue.

Comment: @Jinx88909 YES there is.!

Comment: @CharlesMay YES there is.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AND YES!! the problem is in my TRIGGER portion..hehehe.. I forgot about my trigger..

well this goes this way, I deleted a column namely(USER) in the ORIGINAL TABLE(tblwalkin) then I didn't modify my trigger table.. that's why the ERROR is

Unknown column 'User' in 'NEW' ... the NEW from the error refers to "new.user" from the trigger itself because column User is already deleted from the original.